# Css mask parallax effect

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax, css-mask

I have applied a mask to an image and want the mask to move faster than the image, when scrolling. Since the mask isnt an individual element i cant apply a parallax effect to the mask, even though I would think thats exactly what I would need here, to achieve a smooth result.

How can the desired effect be achieved (preferrably without jQuery)?

Comment: would this example answer your question 
https://codepen.io/jensiegirl/pen/rgNJrM

Comment: @Andam No, since the mask there is for a fixed image.